# How do I set rowstate property to Deleted at Runtime?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to set rowstate property to deleted at Runtime need to modify the rowstate Modified to Deleted.

As i know that row.Delete() method call change the row state to Deleted but it also delete the Row.

Here i just want to change the rowstate to Deleted but datarow should not be deleted:

Sample Code:

```
 Delete delete = new Delete()
                  .from("tb_lib_report_package_link")
                  .where()
                          .add().criteria("lib_report_id  = :pLibReportId ")
                          .and().criteria("package_Id  IN (" + packageLink + ")")
                  .endWhere();
            drow.AcceptChanges();
            drow.Delete();

            DataRow[] dra = new DataRow[] { drow };

             DbAccessManager accessManager = DbAccessFactory.GetDatabaseAccess(DatabaseType.Oracle, "Data Source=SRV",
                                                                              "DEV", "dev", this.AppCookieData["UserId"]);
            accessManager.ClientId = this.AppCookieData["UserId"];
            DbConnection cn = accessManager.CreateConnection();
            delete.ParameterSetter = new ParameterSetter((builder, param, index) =>
            {
                switch (builder.GetColumnName(param))
                {
                    case "pLibReportId":
                        param.DbType = this.ServerCfgReader.DefaultDBProvider.DBDataAccess.GetDbType(drow["LIB_REPORT_ID"].GetType());
                        param.Value = drow["LIB_REPORT_ID"];
                        break;
                    default:
                        throw new NotImplementedException();
                }
            });
            accessManager.Delete(delete, dra, cn);
```

In this i am getting exception that "Deleted row information cannot be accessed through the row."

Comment: what would the benefit of this be? What are you trying to achieve here? also show some code you have currently.

Comment: See here i just want to change the rowstate Modified to deleted at runtime . Currently i am having a DataRow which rowstate is Modified and on basis of Modified rowstate i need to call Delete method in my framework but framework only handles the Deleted Row state in Delete function.

Comment: What do you mean by "it also delete the Row" if you don't call `AcceptChanges` it remains within the datatable and if you have a reference to it in a variable then you can still pas it about and access it's rowstate.

Comment: at runtime i am having only DataRow and when i call the Delete() method on datarow and later on use the same datarow it is throwing exception "'drow.ItemArray' threw an exception of type 'System.Data.DeletedRowInaccessibleException"

Comment: This is what i am getting after delete method call on datarow . Deleted row information cannot be accessed through the row.

Answer (score 5):

As from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.delete%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> The RowState becomes Deleted after you use the Delete method on an
>   existing DataRow. It remains Deleted until you call AcceptChanges. At
>   this time, the DataRow is removed from the table.

So just call `Delete` and until `AcceptChanges` rowstate will be `Deleted`, but row itself will not be removed from datatable. Note: if you are deleting datarow which state is `Added` - it will be removed from datatable immediately after calling `Delete`

**Update**

You can access deleted row data like this:

```
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof (long));
dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof (string));

dt.Rows.Add(1, "xxx");
dt.Rows.Add(2, "yyy");

dt.AcceptChanges(); // now both rows are in 'Unchanged' state

dt.Rows[1].Delete(); // second row now in 'Deleted' state

foreach (DataRow dro in dt.Rows)
{
    if (dro.RowState == DataRowState.Deleted)
        // accessing deleted row
        Console.WriteLine("Deleted row: ID={0}, Name={1}", dro["ID", DataRowVersion.Original], dro["Name", DataRowVersion.Original]);
    else
        // accessing row as usual
       Console.WriteLine("Row: ID={0}, Name={1}", dro["ID"], dro["Name"]);
}

//putting into another array changes nothing in the manner of acessing deleted row
DataRow[] dra = new DataRow[] {dt.Rows[1]};
Console.WriteLine("Deleted row from another array: ID={0}", dra[0]["ID", DataRowVersion.Original]);
```

Comment: Andy thanks for your suggestion but when i called Delete on Datarow and later on when i pass the same datarow it will throwing exception as it will not contain Data.

Comment: Check my sample code posted above. Please suggest what i am missing in this.

Comment: As I said, you can accedd fields of DataRow by using `DataRowVersion.Original` modifier.  So you should access your drow as `drow["LIB_REPORT_ID", DataRowVersion.Original]` and later in `accessManager.Delete` you should access elements of `dra` in the same manner, not by `ItemArray`.

Comment: Its adding Null row in dra Item array.                     drow.Delete();                                                DataRow[] dra = new DataRow[] { drow["LIB_REPORT_ID", DataRowVersion.Original] as DataRow };

Comment: after calling  drow.Delete(); drow deleted its data and when i tried to access drow["LIB_REPORT_ID", DataRowVersion.Original] it is returning null datarow.

Comment: @Jack Of course you will get null if you're trying to get something like `drow["LIB_REPORT_ID", DataRowVersion.Original] as DataRow` as you've wrote. Just because this is not a `DataRow`, but just a value of "LIB_REPORT_ID" field of that DataRow. Finally, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowversion%28v=vs.110%29.aspx for reference about `DataRowVersion` and how to use it.

Comment: can you please show me some sample code where i get drow deleted records and row state as deleted in a new datarow.

Comment: @Jack Oh... well, see the sample

Comment: I am getting exception dra[0].ItemArray' threw an exception of type 'System.Data.DeletedRowInaccessibleException' when i tried drow.Delete();

DataRow[] dra = new DataRow[] { drow};

Comment: Your code  var dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(long));
            dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));

            dt.Rows.Add(1, "xxx");
            dt.Rows.Add(2, "yyy");

            dt.AcceptChanges(); // now both rows are in 'Unchanged' state

            dt.Rows[1].Delete(); // second row now in 'Deleted' state

            DataRow[] dra1 = new DataRow[] { dt.Rows[1] };
 also throwing the same exception dra1[0].ItemArray' threw an exception of type 'System.Data.DeletedRowInaccessibleException'  when i am using dra1 itemarray for my delete operation.

Comment: @Jack, why do you think you can use `ItemArray` to access deleted row data? Have I ever mentioned it? Moreover, some comments above I've clearly said "don't use ItemArray". I've shown you the only possible way of accessing deleted row data in .NET, so if you still want to invent something else - go on, but without me.

Comment: thanks for your response but my delete method is framework driven and it is only take itemArray as input parameter i want an item array instead of DataRow one column original value. Can you please help on this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63922/discussion-between-andy-korneyev-and-jack).

Answer (score 1):

No you certainly can't do that. Per [Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.rowstate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) `RowState` is defined as read-only property (having only a `getter`) like

```
public DataRowState RowState { get; }
```

Comment: The fact that RowState is readonly doesn't matter in this case. Because there are `SetAdded` and `SetModified`, `AcceptChanges` methods which are modifying this property. And even `Delete` until `AcceptChanges` will set RowState to `Deleted` - just as OP wants.

Comment: That's true but what I mean is you can't and shouldn't explicitly set `RowState` property for a datarow and neither it makes sense.